# Truffle, 2_deploy_contract (constructor parameter)

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to create the SampleCrowdsale contract (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol) in Truffle but how can i give the constructor the right parameter?

```
var SampleCrowdsaleToken = artifacts.require("./SampleCrowdsaleToken.sol");
var startTime = 1513728000;
var endTime = 1514592000;
var rate = 1;
var goal = 20;
var cap = 40;
var address = "0x...";
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SampleCrowdsaleToken, startTime, endTime, rate , goal, cap, address);
};
```

Migrate works but he contract doesn't take the right parameter.

What's the problem?

Comment: Just a quick glance, it looks like you need to use `BigNumber`s for `rate`, `goal` and `cap`. The last 2 should be in Wei (using web3.toWei()). Try that and see if it works.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. why it's necessary to do it like this? 
i'm not sure how to implement it that way but i will try to find out.

Comment: It's because the values in Wei are too big for JS, so the API uses `BigNumber` to work around it. The `toWei()` method will convert it for you. You just need to change those two values to `web3.toWei(20, 'ether')`. You can also create a `BigNumber` directly with `new BigNumber()`. Look at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js for more info.

Comment: thank you very much. now migrate works with the right parameter. but how can i get constructor_arguments_in_abi?  const goal = new BigNumber(web3.toWei(2000000000000000000000000000000, 'ether')); -> { [String: '2e+48'] s: 1, e: 48, c: [ 2000000 ] }.  with just taking the 2000000 it does work.

Comment: You're doing too much. The method returns the converted `BigNumber`. Your code should be `const rate = new BigNumber(1); const goal = web3.toWei(20, 'ether'); const cap = web3.toWei(40, 'ether');`

Comment: finally everything works!!! danke danke!!!